# JQgrid multiple columns grouping for server side pagination

Tags: c#, jqgrid

I am developing using ASP.NET MVC  , I tried to do a grouping for multiple columns using jqgrid Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_5.2.1 ,
the grouping column is repeated even if I set only one grouping field , I tries to sorting check bug issue at jGrid but the group not work well unless i set datatype local and set propert GroupColumnby ,

```
 $("#securitiesTable").jqGrid({

        url: urlCurrentPage,
        datatype: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        height: 'auto',
        defaults: {
            recordtext: "View {0} - {1} of {2}",
            emptyrecords: "No records to view",
            loadtext: "Loading...",
            pgtext: "Page {0} of {1}",
            pager: $("#securitiesPager"),
        },
        grouping: true,
        groupingView: {
            //groupField: ['MarketName', 'SecurityName', 'SecurityType'],
            groupField: ['MarketName'],
            groupColumnShow: [false] //,
            // groupDataSorted: true
        },
        colNames: ['Id', 'Market Name', 'Security Name', 'Sector Symbol', //'Security Symbol',
            'Security Type', 'Disabled', 'Suspended', 'Details', 'Edit', 'Delete'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', hidden: true },
            { name: 'MarketName', index: 'MarketName', sorttype: 'string', width: 200 },
            { name: 'SecurityName', index: 'SecurityName', sorttype: 'string', width:100},
            { name: 'SectorSymbol', index: 'SectorSymbol', sorttype: 'string', width: 200 },
            //{ name: 'SecuritySymbol', index: 'SecuritySymbol', sorttype: 'string', width: 200 },
            { name: 'SecurityType', index: 'SecurityType', sorttype: 'int', width: 200, formatter: typeFormatter},
            { name: 'IsDisabled', index: 'IsDisabled', sorttype: 'int', width: 200, formatter: enableDisableFormatter },
            { name: 'IsSuspended', index: 'IsSuspended', width: 200, formatter: suspendedFormatter},
            { name: 'Details', index: 'Details', width: 130, formatter: detailsFormatter },
            { name: 'Edit', index: 'Edit', width: 130, formatter: editFormatter },
            { name: 'Delete', index: 'Delete', width: 130, formatter: deleteFormatter }
        ],
        pager: $("#securitiesPager"),
        rowNum: 10000,
        viewrecords: true,
        width: $(window).width() - 100,
        rowList: [10, 25,50],
        });
```

the above is the section of JQgrid

This is the C# function supposed to do server side pagination [image]

Comment: Could you please post the data which causes this behaviour?

Comment: @TonyTomov using GroupingView in general causes this , i solved this by using GroupByColumn property of jqgrid but for some reason i could not use GroupByColumn colum when type of data t JqGrid is json i think cause it required set manully after grid initialization and reload the Grid